# How to change the last line of this query to inner join

Tags: mysql

I have the following sql statement:

```
SELECT FORMAT(((SUM(sureness)/count(*))+1)/2, 4) FROM tweet 
INNER JOIN entity_topic_epoch_dataitem_relation r ON r.DataitemID = tweet.ID
INNER JOIN epoch ON epoch.ID = r.EpochID 
WHERE epoch.StartDateTime >= '2013/12/05' 
AND epoch.EndDateTime <='2013/12/10' and DataitemType=3  and r.EntityID in(SELECT EntityID
 FROM omid.entity where PartyID=1);
```

My problem is the line r.EntityID in(SELECT EntityID FROM omid.entity where PartyID=1);

because I do not know how to change it to inner join rather than using inside selection(because now this query is very slow and I think if change the last line to inner join instead it gets better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT FORMAT(((SUM(sureness)/count(*))+1)/2, 4) FROM tweet 
INNER JOIN entity_topic_epoch_dataitem_relation r ON r.DataitemID = tweet.ID
INNER JOIN epoch ON epoch.ID = r.EpochID 
INNER JOIN omit.entity AS o ON r.EntityID = o.EntityID
WHERE epoch.StartDateTime >= '2013/12/05' 
AND epoch.EndDateTime <='2013/12/10' and DataitemType=3 
AND o.PartyID=1;
```

But this assumes you'll have only one row per EntityID for a given PartyID in omit.entity. If there could be multiple rows per EntityID, then they'll multiply the rows from the other tables, and your SUM() calculation will be likewise multiplied.